# How can I add a `else` in nginx config file?

Tags: nginx

I have below nginx config file. I'd like to add another `route` which maps everything else to `http://kibana-entrypoint:5601/`. How can I do that in nginx?

```
http {
      server {
          listen       8080;
          server_name  localhost;
          location /es/ {
            proxy_pass  http://es-entrypoint:9200/;
          }
          location /health {
            proxy_pass  http://es-entrypoint:9200/_cluster/health;
          }
          location EVERYTHING_ELSE {
            proxy_pass  http://kibana-entrypoint:5601/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_buffering off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
          }
      }
    }
```

Comment: does [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/857787/how-to-if-else-statement-with-nginx-conf) help you ?

Comment: The `location /` block receives any request that is not handled by any other `location` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for details.